# How do I share jQuery script between pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

what is the best way to share jQuery code between pages? this is the situation:

-------SITUATION---------

I have several different pages that goes this way (pseudo code)

```
 <% render "content/link" , collection => required_links %>
```

In the "content/link" partial

```
 <div class="element_to_be_changed"/>
```

Currently in EVERY PAGE that renders the partial, i call

```
 jQuery.('.element_to_be_changed')... effect that i want...
```

This strikes me as unscalable, but i am not sure what is the best way to handle it. anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Please add more details, and less pseudo-code.

Answer (score 4):

If it is exactly the same on each page put it in an external script and include the script in the pages that use it.